# Using a grammar parser for Python and constructing files from the tree

Tags: python, parsing, grammar

I have a custom made grammar for an interpreted language and I am looking for advice on a parser which will create a tree which I can query.  From the structure I would like to be able to generate code in the interpreted language.  Most grammar parsers that I have seen validate already existing code.  The second part of my question is should the grammar be abstracted to the point that the Python code will substitute symbols in the tree for actual code terminology?  Ideally, I would love be be able to query a root symbol and have returned all the symbols which fall under that root and so forth all the way to a terminal symbol.

Any advice on this process or my vocabulary regarding it would be very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of parser libraries will create an abstract syntax tree (AST) from whatever code it is you're generating; you can use whatever, eg [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). To go from the AST to code, you might have to write functions manually to do that, but it's pretty easy to do that recursively. For example:

```
def generate(ast):
    if ast[0] == '+':
        return generate(ast[1]) + " + " + generate(ast[2])
    elif ast[0] == 'for':
        return "for %s in %s:\n" % (ast[1], generate(ast[2])) + generate(ast[3])
    ...
```

assuming an AST structure that's just a list where the first element is a tag for the node name, followed by the trees for any arguments: `[+, 4, [*, 'x', 5]]`. Of course, you should use whatever your parser library uses, unless you're writing the parser yourself.

I don't understand what you mean by Python code substituting symbols in the tree for actual code terminology.

You could write an easy function to iterate over all the symbols under a root node:

```
def traverse_preorder(ast):
    yield ast[0]
    for arg in ast[1:]:
        for x in traverse_preorder(arg):
            yield x
```

On second thought, the variable name `ast` is maybe a poor choice because of the ast module.

Comment: Thank you, I now have a much better understanding of how I should be going about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use ANTLR.  Version 3 (current) supports [generating Python code](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3PythonTarget).  It will generate an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) automatically during parsing, which you can then traverse.  An important part of this will be annotating your grammar with which tokens are to be treated as subtrees (e.g. operators).